# How to configure JavaScript imports in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

When I run `npx create-next-app`, I get this question ***What import alias would you like configured? ... ** / * )***

I want to be able to use normal ES6 `import` statements for example.

```
import Nav from "../components/Nav"
```

Instead of that, Next.js keeps glitching and makes a wrong import statement like this.

```
import Nav from "../components/Nav**/*"
```

It makes no sense, I do not understand what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The question *"What import alias would you like configured ?"* is not about the import syntax to be used, it's about ["Module path aliases"](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases).

You probably want to just accept the preset option `@/*`.
If you don't understand what this does, you still can import files as you always did.

Justin Dwyer posted a [nice examination](https://dev.to/justindwyer6/what-import-alias-would-you-like-configured-51n4).

Comment: I don't have the `@/*` option, what I have is the `**/*` option on the command line.

I can not import a file from `lib` directory, it throws an error.

`Module not found: Can't resolve '@lib/getAllUsers*/*'`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by myself. I would love to explain this.

In `tsconfig.json`, you can set the path alias for your project, this means setting the entry point of your project.

You can use two methods.

**Method 1**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {

   "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
}

}
```

This way in your project, you can import variables, functions, etc. by using the `@` symbol

```js
import {getAllUsers} from '@/lib/getAllUsers'
```

**Method 2**

```js
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "baseUrl": ".",

   "paths": {
      "./": ["./*"]
    }
}

}
```

This way in your project, you can import variables, functions, etc.

```js
import {getAllUsers} from 'lib/getAllUsers'
```

**Note: Always restart your server after making changes in your tsconfig.json**